# Historical references for Birational Geometry.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, birational-geometry

I'm interested in learning more about the mathematical history of birational geometry. I'm writing my thesis about certain obstructions to various types of rationality (ie. intermediate jacobians, brauer groups), however I'd like to learn more about the history of the subject (I mean pre 20th century). I think it would be interesting to learn about how mathematicians used to think about these questions, for example the existence of 'parametric equations' defining solutions to polynomials. I'm interested in what sort of problems pre 20th century mathematicians were interested in, and what methods they had at their disposal to try and solve them.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have all that much to contribute here, but I believe the birational point of view first arose in the 19th century when geometers were not all that comfortable working in higher-dimensional projective spaces, but nevertheless understood that singular surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ should be thought of as projections of smooth surfaces.

Comment: Perhaps better suited to https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: The canonical reference is Dieudonné, _History of Algebraic Geometry_. The book may be difficult to get, at least  in physical form, but a shorter version (out of which if I recall correctly the book grew) is freely available at https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317664